# Prove: If f and g are two uniformly continuous functions in I, then $\alpha f+\beta g$ is also uniformly continuous in I

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Prove:

If f and g are two uniformly continuous functions in I, then $\alpha f+\beta g$ is also uniformly continuous in I

Where $\alpha , \beta \in R$ and I is a section that can be closed or not.

Do I somehow need to find a general delta and epsilon in order to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y \in I$ we have 
$$|\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x) - \alpha f(y) - \beta g(y)|\leq \alpha |f(x)-f(y)| +\beta |g(x)-g(y)|$$ and the result follows by assumption.